# searching an id in an array of dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have a array of dictionary in JavaScript and I want to add an element to one of the dictionary in the array by matching if an ID is found. 
How to search if an ID is found?

This is my dictionary:

```
{ 
    priyanka: [ { socketid: 'bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA' } ],
    test: [ { socketid: 'Q2n5RzcJqPeLZ5T9AAAB' } ] } ] 
}
```

I want to add an element by searching for `socketid` "bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA" and add an element to the dictionary.

Comment: you want the result object like `priyanka: [ { socketid: 'bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA',word:meaning } ]` or some other way

Comment: Is the dictionary with `socketid` property always the first element in the array?

Comment: shouldnt the title of the question be "searching a value in a dictionary of dictionaries"?

Answer (score 5):

In the current state of the data you'd have to use a linear search at least.

```
var keyToFind = 'Q2n5RzcJqPeLZ5T9AAAB';
for(var i in dictionary){
    if(dictionary[i].socketid == keyToFind){
        // Add an element to the dictionary
        break; // If you want to break out of the loop once you've found a match
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're question is rather confusing but I think what you're trying to do is :

```
var myDict = { 
    priyanka: [ { socketid: 'bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA' } ],
    test    : [ { socketid: 'Q2n5RzcJqPeLZ5T9AAAB' } ],
 }
```

and then looping through the array (although in this case, they only contain one item...)

```
var arr = myDict.priyanka
for(var i=0; i<arr.length ; i++){
    if(arr[i].socketid === 'bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA'){
        var el = /whatever you wanna add?/
        arr.push(el);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = { 
    priyanka: [ { socketid: 'bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA' } ],
    test: [ { socketid: 'Q2n5RzcJqPeLZ5T9AAAB' } ] } ] 
};

myObject.priyanka.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.socketid === 'bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA'){
        // There is a socketid equals to bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA in priyanka
        break;
    } else {
        // Socketid not found
    }
});
```

Be aware that Array.forEach is not fully cross browser compatible, maybe you want to go with a simple `for` loop :

```
for(var i=0; i < myObject.priyanka.length; i++){
    if(myObject.priyanka[i].socketid === 'bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA'){
        // There is a socketid equals to bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA in priyanka
        break;
    } else {
        // Socketid not found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add elements like this

Dictionary

```
var dict = { 
priyanka: [ { socketid: 'bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA' } ],
test: [ { socketid: 'Q2n5RzcJqPeLZ5T9AAAB' } ] }
```

function

```
var addToDict = function (dict,id,element) {
    for(key in dict){   //search in each key of dictionary
       var obj = dict[key];
       if(obj[0].socketid == id)   // if that key contains socketId
         obj.push(element);    // add element to key's array
    }
}
```

call the function

```
addToDict(dict,'bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA',{"word":"meaning"}) 
console.log(dict)  // because object will be passed by reference the `dict` will changed.
```

Comment: @user3805349 you should accept the answers and upvote the comments and answers which are helpful. so other viewers get it helpful. Thanx

Comment: @priyanka (offTopic comment but...) you should really consider to mark an answer as accepted. It's a way to say "thanks" here on SO, but also for other people to fast-spot the answer that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this helper function:

```
function findInDict(dict, predicate) 
{
    for (var prop in dict) {
        if (dict.hasOwnProperty(prop) && predicate(dict[prop], prop, dict)) {
            return prop;
        }
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

Then perform the search:

```
// find property on main dictionary
var prop = findInDict(dict, function(value, name) {
    // name is property name
    // value is property value
    return value[0].socketid == 'bVLmrV8I9JsSyON7AAAA';
});

if (prop === null) {
    // prop doesn't exist, so create one?
}
```